# Running multiple projects on Mule

Tags: project, mule

Is it possible to run multiple Mule projects on the same port, and if so how to do it? Cause the only thing i can do at the moment is run multiple flows in one project, and the idea is to have multiple projects running on the same port with different paths so i can do a wrong configuration (causing undeploy) and still have the others running when that goes down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible since Mule 3.5.0-M4, but you'll have to wait for a few days to try it on a productive version like 3.5.0. You need to create a shared http connector in a domain and reference that connector from your apps.

Comment: Cool, i will run some tests at localhost and wait for final version :) ty!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run multiple projects with same port number provided that the paths are different.